# get selected object from options loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to find a way to bind array of objects within Vue select-element. The case is somewhat as follows:

```
data: {
  ideas: [
    { id: 1, code: "01A", text: "option 1", props: [] }, 
    { id: 2, code: "02A", text: "option 2 , props: [{ details: "something" }]}
  ]},
  currentForm: {
    something: "foo",
    else: "bar",
    ideaCode: "01A",
    text: "option 1"
  }
];
```

... and in HTML ...

```
<select v-model="currentForm.ideaCode" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm(???)">
  <option v-for="i in ideas" value="i">{{ i.text }}<option>
</select>
```

Basically I need to be able to track which **object** user selects, trigger my own change-event, all the while having binding with a single key from another object... selected value / reference-key should be separated from user-selected option/object. **Note: currentForm is not same object-type as option! It only contains some of those properties which option happens to have, and which I'm trying to transfer to options by triggering change-event for user-selection.**

The problem is I haven't figured out how to pass currently selected value for the function OR how to write something like:

```
<select v-model="selectedIdea" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm" :track-by="currentForm.ideaCode">
  <option v-for="i in ideas" value="i">{{ i.text }}<option>
</select>
```

One possible (and working) approach is:

```
<select v-model="currentForm.ideaCode" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm">
  <option v-for="i in ideas" value="i.ideaCode">{{ i.text }}<option>
</select>

setCodeAndLabelForForm: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.ideas.forEach(function(i) {
        if(i.ideaCode == me.currentForm.ideaCode) {
            me.currentForm.ideaCode = i.selectedIdea.ideaCode;
            me.currentForm.text = i.text;
            ... do stuff & run callbacks ...
        }
    });
}
```

... but it just seems terrible. Any better suggestions?

Comment: Unless there is a way to separate way to separate referencing key and v-model, I may need to fallback to tracking only ideaCode -value with v-model and separate object-parsing to @change -event, meaning that I would need to parse that object-array manually within function (filter/map/forEach -solution)... but I would prefer to simply point user-selected object from with template syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question and there have been good suggestions for handling this situation. I cannot remember the exact business-case presented here, but just by a quick glance it looks like I couldn't figure out how to set/initialize right selection afterwards, because handling just the @change event is childs play -- it's the pairing of one single value against list of object-based-options which is harder. What I was most likely looking for was something AngularJS used to have (track-by -property, which matches any given value against selected-option).

Personally now-a-days I would separate UI-logics instead of trying to force 'em to blend together. Most viable approach for myself would be handling list of options and the selected option as one logical area **(ie. data: { list: [...options], selectedIdea: Object })** and separate the "currentForm"-object from selection. Let's break this out:

- selectedIdea is something which needs to trigger change into currentForm-object. It's not any kind of hybrid-model, it's just a plain object, one of the available selections, pure and simple.
- ... and once again: Whenever selectedValue === one of the options, the select-dropdown  is automatically set to right selection.
- "currentForm"-object has a property which can be used to set the selectedIdea. In this case it's the "ideaCode". This ideaCode doesn't automatically do any pairing or such *Component logic **needs** to represent the rules, which trigger selecting the correct option, which matches "ideaCode".*
- Just an extra-though: selectedIdea and currentForm-object are two different logical elements. They could be even separated to different components if one would want do, and in some cases it's really good thing to separate 'em.

So by these statements I guess I would change my select's v-model to be exactly what it's supposed to be: One of the selected objects (change v-model="currentForm.ideaCode" into v-model="selectedIdea" or such). Then I would simply add watcher for that selectedIdea and make any alterations to currentForm-object from there.

How about initializing that option by currentForm.ideaCode ? Do one of the following on create-method:

- Iterate list of available options. When you find option where currentForm.ideaCode == option.code => this.selectedIdea = option
- ... or use ecmascript find-method to do the same
- ... or use underscore/lodash find-method to do the same

Another way would be by using computed value, as suggested Augusto Escobar. Also $ref would work, as suggested by feng zhang, but this approach would still require solution for initializing correct option afterwards (when loading editor with initial values). Thanks to Bhojendra Rauniyar as well -- you were right all along, but I just couldn't comprehend the answer as I couldn't have figured out how to backtrack initial selection.

Thanks for all the suggestions over the year!

Answer (score 5):

You can implement like this:

Create empty object data to track the selected value:

```
currentForm: {}
```

Watch currentForm on the model and pass the selected object:

```
<select v-model="currentForm" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm(currentForm)">
```

Pass in the selected value in `option`: (you were doing right in this step, but I just changed `i` to `idea` as it's little confusing looping index)

```
<option v-for="idea in ideas" :value="idea">{{ idea.text }}<option>
```

Apply your method:

```
setCodeAndLabelForForm(selected) {
  // Now, you have the user selected object
}
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. CurrentForm isn't actually the selected option, but an object which happens to contain those two fields which need to be copied from selected option... currentForm could have ~20 other properties unrelated to "idea" and from your suggestion I believe currentForm would be overwritten by selection... not what I was looking for, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: currentForm will hold only one object not whole. just try it and you'll know it is an easier solution.

Comment: and in your method, you can take property whatever you want... like: `selected.code`

Answer (score 3):

A little bit better workaround: use index in v-for

```
<select v-model="selIdeaIndex" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm">
  <option v-for="(i,idx) in ideas" value="idx">{{ i.text }}<option>
</select>
```

For the js:

```
data: {
  selIdeaIndex:null,
  ideas: [
    { id: 1, code: "01A", text: "option 1", props: [] }, 
    { id: 2, code: "02A", text: "option 2", props: [{ details: "something" }]}
  ]
},
methods:{
    setCodeAndLabelForForm: function() {
        var selIdea = this.ideas[this.selIdeaIndex];
        //Do whatever you wanna do with this selIdea.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, although the this.ideas(this.selIdeaIndex) should be this.ideas[this.selIdeaIndex]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I solve this problem using computed properties like this:

In the JavaScript file (ES6):

```
data () {
    return {
        options: [
            { id: 1, text: "option 1" },
            { id: 2, text: "option 2" }
        ],
        selectedOptionId: 1
    }
},
computed: {
    selectedOption () {
        return _.find(this.options, (option) => {
            return option.id === this.selectedOptionId
        });
    }
}
```

In the HTML file:

```
<select v-model="selectedOptionId">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id" :key="option.id">{{ option.text }}<option>
</select>
```

The '_' symbol is a common JavaScript library called Lodash and I highly recommend the usage. It can make you save some precious time.

Comment: Interesting approach. Very close to my fallback-solution, but I'm bit worried how computed vs change-event would balance out. I'm looking for clear user-triggered input (selection/change), which should handle change-action for selected option only once when change is triggered.

Comment: If you debug it with a breakpoint inside the selectedOption function, you'll see it is triggered only when this.selectedOptionId changes. I guess Vue only recalculates the computed properties when they should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your `option`s will only come from that `v-for="i in ideas"` then the `<option>` indexes will be the same as the `item` indexes.

Thus `<select>.selectedIndex` will be the index of the selected `this.item`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ideas: [
      { id: 1, code: "01A", text: "option 1", props: [] }, 
      { id: 2, code: "02A", text: "option 2" , props: [{ details: "something" }]}
    ],
    currentForm: {ideaCode: "01A", text: "option 1"}
  },
  methods: {
    setCodeAndLabelForForm: function(selectedIndex) {
      var selectedIdea = this.ideas[selectedIndex];
      this.currentForm = {ideaCode: selectedIdea.code, text: selectedIdea.text};
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="currentForm.ideaCode" @change="setCodeAndLabelForForm($event.target.selectedIndex)">
    <option v-for="i in ideas" :value="i.code">{{ i.text }}</option>
  </select>
  <br> currentForm: {{ currentForm }}
</div>
```

Differences from yours: `@change="setCodeAndLabelForForm($event.target.selectedIndex)"` and the `setCodeAndLabelForForm` implementation.

Comment: Quite close to my fallback-suggestion, except that my option wouldn't rely on index and would thus probably be safer as it validates acceptable option within forEach-loop... but I still find my option poor solution in comparison to what I'm looking for (directly from template). Thanks for giving it a thought none-the-less!  BTW: I did try similar approach by passing $event.target.data , but apparently I got only [object object] -string instead of actual object, and I still had trouble separating model vs referring key (which should contain the selected value and/or referral)

Comment: You get `[object Object]` because it converts to string when passing data attributes. Other than the solution I gave here, you could filter the collection, like you did (though I'd use `var selectedIdea = this.ideas.find(i => i.code === this.currentForm.ideaCode);` and the rest like my code - without having to pass `$event` as arg). Using a regular `<select>`, that's it. If that does not suffice to you, I recommend using a custom component (a `v-select` of vuetify, or one of the many standalone ones you will find on the internet), it will make this whole set/get value situation much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

A humble way is using `$ref`.

There is a solution using `$ref` and `@change`.

[Vue.js get selected options' raw object](https://codepen.io/1010543618/pen/yLLQNbW)